# in-browser / online code editor for teaching?

Tags: web-development, ide, editor

I'm teaching kids (like in a classroom setting) to make a website in a live-coding type format. I'm sharing my screen, of course, but since kids are prone to syntax errors, I want to publish my code somewhere they can see it and check their own code against and copy/paste if need be (so I don't have to keep telling them over and over again to check their syntax).

Here's my wishlist:

- it needs to be FREE (or at least have a free version that contains everything I need
- view-only mode (or like [codepen pro](http://codepen.io)'s "professor mode" or [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io)'s classroom mode)
- it needs to use either textarea, codemirror, or ace so I can use Sublime's [GhostText](https://github.com/fregante/GhostText) plugin to automatically "mirror" the code I write in my IDE ([here's a list](https://ghosttext.fregante.com/troubleshooting/) of the supported editor fields - [repl.it](http://repl.it) and codesandbox.io do not work)
- it needs to support a folder / directory structure with multiple files in one place (just like a normal IDE, like visual studio code)
- there needs to be a link I can share to the students where they can see my code like repl.it
- I do NOT need any of the console / terminal / any extra features
- it must be online; I don't want to ask them to download anything - aka no Remote Collab for SublimeText or Visual Studio Live Share or Teletype for Atom)
- it should update live and automatically instantly (like Google Docs, not every 30 seconds). emphasis on automatically - I shouldn't have to ctrl+s every 5 seconds.

example:

1. [codeshare.io](http://codeshare.io) would be good, but it needs (a) to allow a folder / directory structure with multiple files in one place and (b) a view-only mode so students cannot edit

I know there are a bunch of remote-pairing / coding interview type things, but they're usually not view-only or it's only one-on-one. I also do NOT need any audio call / chat features.

I've literally looked EVERYWHERE. [glitch](http://glitch.com) actually works, I think, but please let me know if there are alternatives. If there's another innovative solution (like using google apps script to load it into google docs, etc), that could work too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it but I have heard good things about [Etherpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etherpad). The teacher must install and tweak the software;  for the students the experience is  visiting just another web site (and editing stuff). You can turn Etherpad into an IDE with [Plugins](https://static.etherpad.org/index.html), e.g. [ep_codepad](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_codepad) and [ep_syntax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_syntax).

That is a type of [Collaborative real-time editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor).